# Spring @Transactional not inserting into table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am having trouble saving data into the database. I can see the insert SQL statement in the logs and also I write the generated ID to the log. The problem I am facing is the data is not being persisted into the database from the session.
I don't have any trouble fetching the data from the database. The user I am using has read/write access to the database and also I don't get any errors.

I am using Spring 4.2.3, Hibernate 5.5.0, MySQL 5 and Primefaces 5.3.

I search all the forums and found nothing that helped me.
Has anybody faced similar issues?

Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "borrower", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "borrower_id")
})
public class Borrower implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "borrower_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer borrowerId;
    @Column(name = "borrower_code", nullable = true, length = 20)
    private String borrowerCode;
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = true, length = 45)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = true, length = 45)
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "borrower_status", nullable = false, length = 15)
    private String borrowerStatus;
    @Column(name = "email_id", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String emailId;

    public Borrower() {
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

DAO

```
public class BorrowerDAOImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements BorrowerDAO {

    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public boolean saveBorrower(Borrower borrower) {
        try {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.persist(borrower);
            session.flush();
            logger.info("Borrower '{} {}' with Borrower ID '{}' saved successfully.", borrower.getFirstName(), borrower.getLastName(), borrower.getBorrowerId());
            session.disconnect();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Unable to add new borrower '{} {}', error: ", borrower.getFirstName(), borrower.getLastName(), e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service("borrowerBO")
@SessionScoped
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class BorrowerBOImpl implements BorrowerBO {

    @Autowired
    BorrowerDAO borrowerDAO;

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    @Override
    public boolean saveBorrower(Borrower borrower) {
        return borrowerDAO.saveBorrower(borrower);
    }

    public BorrowerDAO getBorrowerDAO() {
        return borrowerDAO;
    }

    public void setBorrowerDAO(BorrowerDAO borrowerDAO) {
        this.borrowerDAO = borrowerDAO;
    }
}
```

Spring Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.movielibrary.bo"/>

    <!-- SessionFactory bean -->
    <import resource="classpath:HibernateSessionFactory.xml"/>

    <!-- Annotate transaction behaviour -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <!-- Transaction manager bean -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Bean declaration -->
    <bean id="borrowerBO" class="com.movielibrary.bo.impl.BorrowerBOImpl">
        <property name="borrowerDAO" ref="borrowerDAO" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="borrowerDAO" class="com.movielibrary.dao.impl.BorrowerDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Hibernate Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">

    <!-- Database configuration bean -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_db?relaxAutoCommit=true" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <!-- SessionFactory bean -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <!-- Hibernate annotations property -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.movielibrary.model" />   
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.movielibrary.model.Borrower</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Can you try it by changing `@Transactional(readOnly = false)` with `@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` on your `saveBorrower` method

Comment: How is the configuration loaded (show your web.xml or initializer code) and how is this service invoked? Assuming `@SessionScoped` is the cdi or sf one that isn't going to do anything. Next to that you will have 2 instances of your class one with component-scanning and one from xml.

Comment: What if you remove @Transactional(readOnly = true) from the class and place on methods?

Comment: @Patrick, thanks for the sugestion, I will try that and let you know.

Comment: @Deinum, I will comment component-scanning and see whether it works.

Comment: I tried all the suggestions, commented @SessionScoped, commented component-scan in spring config file and removed @Transactional(readOnly=true) from the class. Still the data is not persisting in the database. I can see the data in the session.

Comment: Spring config initializer code in web.xml 
`<context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
     </context-param>
     <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
     </listener>
     <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
        </listener>`